# Search snaps using regex/patterns

Tags: command-line, snap, regex

Is it possible to narrow down the results of `snap find <package>`? For example, if I search for `code` as:

`snap find code`

can I add another keyword that should be looked at in `publisher` or `summery`?
something like `snap find code&editing`

Comment: `code&editing` doesn't look like any regex or wildcard pattern. You can use a prefix search (so `code*`). But going by [the API docs](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapd-api#heading--find), it doesn't look like searching in other fields is supported.

Comment: The powerful text processing tools of the terminal allow to do anything. The output of snap find could be piped into awk for listing a specific column only and then piped into grepped to find a specific wildcard pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To add another keyword, just add a space and the next word you want to use to narrow down the results. For example:

```
snap find code editing
```

or

```
snap find code IDE
```